# ¿Cómo hacer scraping a una página hija con Puppeteer?

Tags: nodejs, puppeteer

Estoy haciendo un software que hace **web scraping**, pero parte de la información que necesito, está después de un enlace (`<a>`). Para lograr acceder a la información de esta segunda página, he utilizado el siguiente código:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); // Require Puppeteer

async function readSubPage(url, page) {
    await page.goto(url)

    let sub = page.evaluate(() => {
        let abstract = document.querySelectorAll('div.trans-abstract')

        let subs = []

        for (let ab of abstract) {
            let title = abstract.querySelector('p.sec')
            let text = abstract.querySelector('p :nth-child(2)')

            let texts = {
                spanish: title.innerText === 'Abstract: ' || title.innerText === 'abstract: ' || title.innerText === 'ABSTRACT: ' ? text.innerText : 'Abstract not available in english.',
                english: title.innerText === 'Resumen: ' || title.innerText === 'resumen: ' || title.innerText === 'RESUMEN: ' ? text.innerText : 'Resumen no disponible en español.'
            }

            subs.push(texts)
        }

        return texts
    })

    console.log(subs)
    return subs
}

async function readScielo(query) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto(query)

    var art = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        const container = document.querySelectorAll('div.item > div.col-md-11.col-sm-10.col-xs-11 >div.line > a')
        
        let list = []

        for (let element of container) {
            const strong = element.querySelector('strong.title')

            let links = {}

            if (strong !== null) {
                let abstracts = null

                try {
                    abstracts = await readSubPage(element.href, page)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                }

                links = {
                    link: element.href,
                    text: strong.innerText,
                    abstracts: abstracts
                }

                list.push(links)
            }
        }

        return list
    })

    browser.close()
    return art;
}

module.exports = readScielo
```

En realidad, el código funciona, excepto en la función llamada `readSubPage()`, que ahí no hay ninguna función. Quisiera saber cómo hacer esto con `async await`, o si existe una función en puppeteer que me permita hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tiene un error de "typo" porque en su código está retornando `texts` y no `subs` que es el array acumulador, pruebe con este código a ver si le funciona:

```
async function readSubPage(url, page) {
  await page.goto(url)

  const sub = page.evaluate(() => {
    const abstract = document.querySelectorAll('div.trans-abstract')

    const subs = []

    for(let ab of abstract) {
      let title = abstract.querySelector('p.sec')
      let text = abstract.querySelector('p :nth-child(2)')

      let texts = {
        spanish: title.innerText === 'Abstract: ' || title.innerText === 'abstract: ' || title.innerText === 'ABSTRACT: ' ? text.innerText : 'Abstract not available in english.',
        english: title.innerText === 'Resumen: ' || title.innerText === 'resumen: ' || title.innerText === 'RESUMEN: ' ? text.innerText : 'Resumen no disponible en español.'
      }

      subs.push(texts)
    }

    return subs
  })

  console.log(sub)
  return sub
}
```

Por cierto, el uso de `const`y `let` no debería modificar el resultado de su código, pero es buena práctica usarlos adecuadamente. Solamente use `let` cuando vaya a modificar la definición de la variable.

Comment: Bueno, al menos la consola ya me muestra un error. Quité `try {} catch {}` y la consola me dice que **Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: readSubPage is not defined**.